# Changing a div opacity on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked through various pages, but have not managed to find a working solution. I want the text in my div to get more transparent gradually when I scroll. Please, can anybody help? Here is my code:

```
<script src = "/js/titleScroll.js"></script>
<div class = "header-title">


    <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $('header-title').css('opacity', 0.8);
    } else {
      $('header-title').css('opacity', 1);
    }
  });
});
```

and here is my css:

```
.header-title {
width: 80%;
height: 100px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
font-size: 1.5em;   
text-align: center;
transform: translateX(-50%); 
margin-top: -50px;
position: relative;
max-width: 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
position: float;

}

.header-title h1 {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #d1d1d1;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;


}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try `$('html,body').scroll()`.

Comment: I replaced $(window).scroll(function() with $('html,body').scroll(function() but sadly nothing. (The bracket is closed off later.)

Comment: Oh. You have a `.` missing. `$(.header-title)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, currently you are just triggering 0.8 opacity when user is not at top of the page. Try to get top offset each time scroll is executed and then apply opacity based on that offset, it can be linear function, or more complex ones - it's up to you how it's gonna fade in/out.

Here's very quick working example:

```
<head>
    <style>

    body {
        min-height: 4000px;
    }

    .header-title {
        position: fixed;
        width: 80%;
        height: 100px;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-align: center;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        margin-top: -50px;
        max-width: 100%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .header-title h1 {
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #d1d1d1;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function(event) {
            let scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
            let opacity = 1 - (scroll / 1000);
            if (opacity >= 0) {
                $('.header-title').css('opacity', opacity);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div class = "header-title">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/un2bdvfm/

Comment: This works as I want, thank you, but do you know how to put that script in an external file? Thanks,

Comment: Create new main.js file, put there code which is in <script> tag. Then import the file in let's say beginning of body <script src="path to your file"></script>